# How to configure AdminLTE 3 javascript links with laravel 6?

Tags: laravel, laravel-6, adminlte

I configured AdminLTE with laravel 6. I am getting error 404 in console. I used NPM to install adminLTE, my adminlte files are in node_modules folder. Kindly look at the link if I am doing it right.

**File structure I have**

```
|-> node_modules

|-> resources

     |-> views

          |-> admin

                |-> users

                      |->index.blade.php
```

**A link from index.blade.php**

```
<script src="../../node_modules/admin-lte/plugins/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you doing like this? Your jquery and other necessary plugins are already included in `app.js` file. Just run `npm run dev`. And then include the public `js/app.js` to your index.blade.php file.
If you need extra plugins just include them in `bootstrap.js` file.

Note:If your `app.js` is empty just run `composer require laravel/ui`.It will create app.js and bootstrap.js with necessary configraton.

Comment: I am already using 
<script src="{{asset('js/app.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{asset('js/bootstrap.js')}}"></script>

but the adminlte html page has some other links going to plugins. These plugins are in node_modules in my project folder. What will be the best way I can use them?

Comment: Like I said you should load bootstrap, jquery and other plugins inside bootstrap. Then `npm run dev` which will compile all your js to app.js.    Alternatively you can use composer to download adminlte. Then copy required asset to public directory and you can easily load your required plugins.

Comment: Got it, man. Thank you. I downloaded adminlte. Now I just have to copy to the pubic folder and the connect through asset?